# Do I need to restart to find newly added blocks?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've got an existing survival game in Minecrat PE that was started in v0.7.4(IIRC), having just updated and got v0.8.0, will I be able to find the new plant and ore types (for example) in my existing game, or do I need to start a new one?

I'm on an iPad retina (4th gen) with iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't have to for this particular patch, because the update(s) consist of things needing to be crafted. If you want to be on the safe side, make a new world. You can visit [Pocket Edition version history](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_version_history#0.8.0), to see what has been updated.

Comment: Good answer to the question. I'd like to see a more general answer as well, for the sake of completeness.